# Switching between fragments while previous animation is running

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I have a TabManager that triggers a transition between fragments complete with nice sliding animation.

This works nicely if I wait for each transition's animation to complete before changing to the next tab. If however I decide to rapidly switch tabs then the animations appear to conflict with each other and my fragments end up animating in incorrect directions.

Is there any way to cancel any animations that might still be running on previous transitions when starting a new one?

My code is as follows:

> @Override
>           public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
>
> ```
>       hostActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
>
>         TabInfo newTab = tabs.get(tabId);
>         if (lastTab != newTab) {
>             FragmentTransaction ft = hostActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
>
>             if (newTab != null) {
>                 if (newTab.fragment == null) {
>                     newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(hostActivity, newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
>                 }
>             }
>
>             if(lastTab != null && newTab != null)
>             {
>               if(lastTab.index < newTab.index)
>               {                       
>                   ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_right, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
>               }
>               else
>               {
>                   ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_left, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);
>               }
>             }
>
>             ft.replace(containerID, newTab.fragment);
>
>             ft.commit();
> ```